# Saving of Numeric with decimal to txt File from datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, decimal, text-files

This is my code for saving the values from data grid view to text file:

```
Private Sub TextFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextFileToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim filename As String = String.Empty
    Dim sfd1 As New SaveFileDialog()

    sfd1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    sfd1.FilterIndex = 2
    sfd1.RestoreDirectory = True
    sfd1.Title = "Save Text File"

    If sfd1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        If sfd1.FileName = String.Empty Then
            MsgBox("Please input filename")
        Else
            filename = sfd1.FileName.ToString
            Saveto_TextFile(dvList, filename)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Sub Saveto_TextFile(ByVal dvList As DataGridView, ByVal filename As String)
    Dim numCols As Integer = dvList.ColumnCount - 1
    Dim numRows As Integer = dvList.RowCount
    Dim strDestinationFile As String = "" & filename & ".txt"
    Dim tw As TextWriter = New StreamWriter(strDestinationFile)

    For dvRow As Integer = 0 To numRows - 1
        'checking if the checkbox is checked, then write to text file
        If dvList.Rows(dvRow).Cells.Item(0).Value = True Then
            tw.Write("True")
            tw.Write(", ")
        Else
            tw.Write("False")
            tw.Write(", ")
        End If

        'write the remaining rows in the text file
        For dvCol As Integer = 1 To numCols
            tw.Write(dvList.Rows(dvRow).Cells(dvCol).Value)
            If (dvCol <> numCols) Then
                tw.Write(", ")
            End If
        Next
        tw.WriteLine()
    Next
    tw.Close()
End Sub
```

This code is perfectly working, but my only concern is that I set up the property of my data grid view to `Numeric` with 2 decimal places. When I'm saving it to the text file, it removes the decimal places.

What can I do to keep the decimal places in the text file?

Comment: I don't know if we can say the code is working perfectly... :) 

Are you getting any output in your text file?

Comment: @Tim:  Hi sir, yes I am getting an output from datagridview to txt file, but the number values in the txt file do not have decimals, but in the datagridview, there are decimal values :)

Comment: @Matthew How do you format your DataGridView? Did you do it programamtically or using the user interface

Comment: @Alex: Hi sir, I already know my problem, its just that I am saving only numbers that do not have decimal places, but if the numbers have decimal places, its working, sorry its my fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your `SaveTo_TextFile` method. I added two columns to my dvList [Column1] and [Column2]. I was able to save the decimal value I entered in [Column2] successfully.

I do not know how you formatted your DataGridView column but mine is only a DataGridViewTextBoxCell with no formatting.

If I used formatting, this is what I would set my numeric column's row cellstyle to:

```
dvList.Columns("Column2").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
```

**SaveTo_TextFile** method

```
Private Sub Saveto_TextFile(ByVal dvList As DataGridView, ByVal filename As String)
    Dim numCols As Integer = dvList.ColumnCount - 1
    Dim numRows As Integer = dvList.RowCount
    Dim strDestinationFile As String = "" & filename & ".txt"
    Dim tw As TextWriter = New StreamWriter(strDestinationFile)

    For dvRow As Integer = 0 To numRows - 1
        'checking if the checkbox is checked, then write to text file
        If dvList.Rows(dvRow).Cells("Column1").Value = True Then
            tw.WriteLine(dvList.Rows(dvRow).Cells("Column2").Value) 'Column2 is the name of the column ... You can also use an index here
        Else
            tw.WriteLine("Not Checked")
        End If

        'write the remaining rows in the text file
        For dvCol As Integer = 1 To numCols
            tw.WriteLine(dvList.Rows(dvRow).Cells(dvCol).Value)
            If (dvCol <> numCols) Then
                tw.WriteLine("???")
            End If
        Next
        tw.WriteLine()
    Next
    tw.Close()
End Sub
```